# Flutter, Access the padding value of parent container widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a GridView widget nested inside of a SizedBox widget nested inside of a Container widget

```
    Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: min(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) -
            20,
        height: min(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) -
            20,
        child: GridView.count(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          crossAxisCount: sqrt(tiles.length).round(),
          mainAxisSpacing: 5,
          crossAxisSpacing: 5,
          children: tiles,
          shrinkWrap: true,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

The Container Widget has an edge inset of 10, so in the SizedBox I want the width and height to be the min screen width/height minus this edge inset (so minus 20 since it's on each side).

How can I read values of a parent widget so that I can know it's edgeInset? Can a MediaQuery accomplish this through the context?

I know that I can just store the edge inset as a variable earlier on and use that in both places, but as I am trying to learn Flutter I am more curious if there is a way to read the values/properties of parent widgets so that their children can reference them on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide some Widget a global key

final _key = GlobalKey();

```
Table(
   key: _key,
   children: _getTableRows(),
);
```

then you can calculate the size of the widget like this:

```
void _getSize(_) {
final RenderBox _boardRender = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
final boardSize = MediaQuery.of(_key.currentContext).size;
final boardOffset = _boardRender.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

//print('$boardSize:$boardOffset:$cellSize');
```

}

You may look at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html

Comment: This is perfect, and GlobalKey() I assume just generates a unique identifier each different time I use it?

Answer (score 0):

`Container` has a somewhat complicated behaviour so the answer to your question would depend on who the parent of the `container` is.
[From the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html):

> Container tries, in order: to honor alignment, to size itself to the child, to honor the width, height, and constraints, to expand to fit the parent, to be as small as possible.

For example: If you place your container in the `body` paramenter of a `Scaffold` and remove the `SizedBox` then `GridView` will fill the screen and will have the padding you specified. (In which case you don't even need `Container` and you can just use `Padding` widget instead.)

More broadly speaking Flutter works in a different paradigm where you don't need to "know" specifics of your parent as you potentialy can place any widget in any other widget.